# How to draw an excel chart from two columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Consider the following table:

```
1970 - 4705
1980 - 4771
1990 - 4998
2000 - 5181
2001 - 5195
2002 - 5205
```

The left number is `x`, the right is `f(x)`. (The numbers are in separate excel columns)

I need to create a chart for `f(x)` from `x` in range `[a;b]`, so that it will interpolate between given values of from this table

When I make a graph, excel considers difference in `x` between adjacent measurements equal:
[image]

(On this graph `2002` is as far from `2000` as `2000` from `1990`).

How can I change it without creating a dumb column for numbers in range `[1900;2011]`?

EDIT: I see no XY chart in excel. At least, poibnt chart produces the same results and doesn't let to change x axis:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is treating the X values as categories rather than numbers.  It does that with certain kinds of graphs regardless of the datatype.  A bar graph is one of those.  Start with an XY chart (the button is labelled "scatter" chart), which treats the X values as a continuous variable.

Comment: Can you show the location of XY chart on a screenshot? I see point chart and graph, but they do not help. I'm using excel 2010. Should it be there?

Comment: I found a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhHYUL-HrKs Thanks!